# Trouble on re-installing Ruby from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

I am using `rvm` (Ruby Version Manager) and I deleted some gems by running the `gem update --system` command. I had some serious problem so I decided to reinstall `rvm` and `ruby 1.9.2` on my local machine (MacOS Snow Leopard 10.6.7).

Now, if I run the`rails s` command I get the following

```
$ rails s
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

**What I can do to solve the problem?**

---

Other command outputs are:

```
$ which ruby
/Users/<my_username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby

$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a clean 1.9.2 install with rails:

```
$ rvm remove 1.9.2
$ rvm install 1.9.2
$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
$ gem install rails
```

Comment: I just did that myself. In the meantime I solved the problem. Thanks, anyway.