# DelayedJob: How to solve the problem "Job failed to load"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, delayed-job

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and DelayedJob. As many people on the web I get the "`Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck`" error, but I think I discovered at least what generates the error (in my case). I have an ActiveModel like the following:

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Dirty
  extend  ActiveModel::Naming
  extend  ActiveModel::Translation

  attr_accessor :full_name, :email, :subject, :message

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.keys.each do |attr|
      instance_variable_set "@" + attr.to_s, attributes[attr.to_sym]
    end
  end

  validates_presence_of :full_name, :email, :subject, :message    

  def persist
    @persisted = true
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

The related controller action is:

```
def contact
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

  if @contact.valid?
    ::Contact::Mailer.delay.contact(@contact)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => :contact }
    end
  end
end
```

*I noted that my problem with the "famous"\"infamous" `Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck` happens only if I run the `@contact.valid?`*. If I re-implement the above controller action like this:

```
def contact
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

  ::Contact::Mailer.delay.contact(@contact)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
  end
end
```

all work as expected: I don't get the error and the e-mail is successfully sent. *In few words, when I run `@contact.valid?` inside the controller action* (I can run that also without using the `if ... else` statement) *it generates the `Job failed to load` error*. I really do not understand this strange behavior related to the DelayedJob gem and the `valid?` method.

**Why it happens? How can I solve the problem?**

---

*More info* at [DelayedJob: “Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496779/delayedjob-job-failed-to-load-uninitialized-constant-sycksyck)

---

**UPDATES**

If I debug the `@contact.errors` in both **cases** using or not using the `@contact.valid?` method...

**... when** I use the `@contact.valid?` method (DelayedJob does not work) I get

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000101759408 @base=#<Contact:0x000001017597f0 @full_name="Sample name", @email="foo@bar.com", @subject="Sample subject", @message="Sample message content.", @validation_context=nil, @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000101759408 ...>>, @messages={}>
```

**... when** I *do not* use the `@contact.valid?` method (DelayedJob works) I get

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000101759408 @base=#<Contact:0x000001017597f0 @full_name="Sample name", @email="foo@bar.com", @subject="Sample subject", @message="Sample message content.", @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000101759408 ...>>, @messages={}>
```

*Note that in the second case the `@validation_context=nil` is not present and that in both cases there is a "nested" `<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000010175940 ...>` statement.* **Is that a bug?**

Comment: I'm encountering the very same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. You can redefine the ['Object#to_yaml_properties'](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/syck/rdoc/Object.html#to_yaml_properties-method) method within your Contact class to only include the properties you need. And thus exclude the 'errors' variable.

```
def to_yaml_properties
  ['@full_name', '@email', '@subject', '@message']
end
```

Hope this helps.